# Can we tell if the mouse actually clicked on a checkbox in Java?

Tags: java, swing, checkbox, click, mouseevent

Here is the scenario. I have an swing applet with tons of checkboxes. some of them are disabled/unchecked when checking another. Each `ItemStateChange()` event executes a method to parse the entire form for changes. Is there a way to tell if an `ItemStateChange()` event was triggered due to a mouse click or from a `setSelected()` call?

The `ItemStateChange()` for each checkbox has the standard parameter `java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt`

I'd like to only call the processOrder() method once when a box is clicked. Right now it fires for each change thats made, regardless of whether the change happened from `setSelected()`. Sometimes there are 10+ `parseForm();` calls from a single click.

Comment: there was an answer here that was deleted before I could comment. It showed `if (evt.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {`. this is preventing the method call to `parseForm()` when using `setSelected()` to change the state. It does exactly what I want. I'm not sure why the answer was deleted

Comment: after closer examination, it is not working if I uncheck the box. I guess thats why it was deleted...

Answer (score 1):

You can't tell whether the source of the event is a mouse click or a setSelected call from the ItemEvent.

It sounds like you have a loop in your check box logic.  You might want to add a controller that handles the events and sets each checkbox yet ignores events that occur due to calling setSelected on other check boxes.

Comment: not a loop, just several calls made due to several `ItemStateChange()` events. If 1 checkbox changes the state of 3 others, there are 4 calls to `parseOrder()` because each `ItemStateChange()` calls it

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to tell if an ItemStateChange() event was triggered due to a mouse click or from a setSelected() call?

If your application manually invokes the setSelected() method then you can use code like:

```
checkBox.removeItemListener(...);
checkBox.setSelected(...);
checkBox.addItemListener(...);
```

Comment: The entire application has hundreds of checkboxes spread across many panes and panels. The applet was created in NetBeans and uses the code generator to add the event handlers. I cannot edit the code produced. Here is what NetBeans gives me.. `cb1.addItemListener(new java.awt.event.ItemListener() {
    public void itemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {
        cb1ItemStateChanged(evt);
    }
});`

can i get the method name out of there so I can reattach it?

Comment: This sounds like a monster of a GUI.  Would some consolidation help?  Would you be better off for instance using a JTable with checkboxes in some columns?  Also this is just personal opinion but GUI's like this created in NetBeans scare me.  It's easy to lose control of them.

Comment: Well unfortunately, I am a java beginner and was forced to use it for this tool. My background is in C and I normally work with web scripting in PHP, ASP and JS. It would take an investment in time to rebuild it and thats not likely to get approved. It really is a mammoth GUI and I could not have done it if not for NetBeans. I'm only trying to save a few processor cycles now. the application itself is, for the most part, complete.

Comment: the interface is a collection of panels which group like items. There are dozens of panels spread over several JTabbedPane(s). The focus was on usablility and as it stands, this is a very user friendly interface. I don't think I can change it much, but then again I haven't seen any examples of JTable yet.

Comment: @DewBoy3d "It would take an investment in time to rebuild it and thats not likely to get approved." .."I cannot edit the code produced."  Given the code you have is not editable and not working - it seems that you cannot afford *not* to rewrite it (using Java this time, rather than an IDE).

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to change to use a MouseListener instead of an ItemListener and respond to the mouseClicked() event you will only receive the events for the checkbox selected by the user.